# When to start using the selection set in a Back Propagation Neural Network?

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

Beginner on ANNs:

I am implementing a back propagation neural network to predict the price of gold. I know that I have to split my data into training data, selection data and test data.

However I unsure How to go on about using these sets of data. At first I was training the data network with my training set then after it's trained I am getting a number of inputs to my network from the test set and comparing the output.

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right and were does the selection set come in ?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is:

1. Train the network for a little while on the training set.
2. Evaluate the network on a second set, often called the validation set. Probably what you're calling the selection set.
3. Train the network a little more on the training set.
4. Evaluate the new network on the selection set again.
5. Which did better, the old network or the new network? If the new network is better, we're still getting some use out of training, so goto 3. If the new network is worse, more training will probably only hurt. Use the previously version of the network, since it did better.

In this way, you can tell when to stop training.

One easy modification to this is to always keep track of the best network seen so far, and we only stop training when we see some number (say, three) of training attempts that do worse in a row.

The third set, the test set, is necessary because the selection set is, if indirectly, involved in the training process. Final evaluation must be done on data that was not used at all during training.

This sort of thing is sufficient for simple experiments, but in general you'll want to use [cross-validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) to get a better idea of your system's performance.

Comment: Great! You couldn't have given a better explanation thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to leave a comment just to say that validation sets are a good place for model-dependent hyper-parameter tuning, but I'm new here and hence lack the reputation points to do so. To make this more worthy of a separate posting, I've included an outline of my own train-validate-test process. In practice, my workflow is as follows:

1. Identify, collect, and clean data. Try to limit complaining during data munging process.
2. Split data into three sets: training, validation, test.
3. Establish two "base" models for evaluating more complex models built later on in the process. The                 first of these models is typically a basic linear/logistic regression using all possible features. The second models uses only the most obviously informative (initial identification of informative features depends on use case, typically involves combination of domain knowledge, basic  clustering, simple correlation).
4. Begin more empirical feature selection (i.e. unsupervised NN, but usually random forest) and prototype a broad range of models using the training set.
5. Eliminate poorly performing models as well as uninformative features
6. Compare performance of remaining models against each other and the "base" models, using a modified version of the training set (same data, but sans uninformative features). Toss under-performing models.
7. Using the validation set, tune the appropriate hyper-parameters for each of the models (either by hand or gridsearch). Further reduce the number of models in consideration, ideally to just 2-3 (excluding base models).
8. Finally, evaluate model performance (with optimized hyper-parameters) on the test set. Again, compare models among themselves and against the base models. Make final model choice based on a problem-specific appropriate combination of computational complexity/cost, ease of interpretation/transparency/"explainability", and improvement over and/or performance vs base models.